# Nexus 7s shifter: how to replace cable?

Tags: shimano, shifter

I've got this part on my bike:
[image]

A shimano nexus 7s shifter. The bowden cable's inner lining is worn after 17 years so I was trying to replace it. But what I can't find is how to disassemble the shifter and replace the cable from there. Is that even possible?

Comment: This [guide](http://drauh.typepad.com/blog/2015/07/replacing-shifter-cable-for-shimano-nexus-revo-shift-8-with-alfine-hub.html) looks useful. Although for a slightly different model, I'd compare it against what you have.

Comment: It's certainly possible to replace the cable.  Some of them are a bear to work on, though.  The link in Christian's comment looks like a good starting point.

Comment: The bike shop replaced the cable for me, according to them it doesn't have a screw like the guide Christian posted but after the top plate is off the assembly is sort of clamped in there so you'll have to pry it apart or something.

Comment: @Plumpie Could you please add an answer and accept it then?  Just so we can get this off our "unanswered" queue?

Comment: its still unanswered imo?

Comment: @Plumpie - you would answer it with "The bike shop replaced the cable for me, according to them it doesn't have a screw like the guide Christian posted but after the top plate is off the assembly is sort of clamped in there so you'll have to pry it apart or something." and then mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Once you unlink the cable from the hub slide the sheath away from the cord.
Then, slide the plug marked on the photo to open the hole.
[image]

Set the shifter to 7th gear.
Push the cord toward the shifter. The cord ending should appear in the hole. Pull it.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience. the inner cable will push through a hole in the hand-grip side or the edge facing the ground.  There will be a black or grey plastic grub screw that will use a screwdriver, torx or hex key to remove.  It won't be tight.  The hole will be large enough for the round end of the bowden cable to fit through.

Again, *if you have this hole* then you do not need to remove the top plate.

Not a great picture but similar concept, opening an access hole to push the inner through:
[image: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/WKc06Kvd0f4/maxresdefault.jpg]

Since you're changing the inner, its prudent too change the outer too.

Comment: The 7s shifter unfortunately doesn't work like this, you can make a hole large enough for the bowden cable but the cable is still locked inside

Comment: I was working on one last week that had a rubber plug in the hole.  (The plug's somewhere on the floor now -- it's tiny and disappeared as soon as it came out.)